# C# - Set (hundreds of) StorageFiles as BitmapImages (Without Stream)

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, storagefile

I'm trying to get all the photos from the device's pictures library and show then on the app using a `<GridView/>` with an `<Image/>` inside it's item template, but I didn't find a way to do that without issues.
I need to create `BitmapImages` from the `StorageFiles` that I get.

First I tried creating the `BitmapImage`s and setting the `UriSource` as new `Uri`s with the files paths, like this:

```
var picsLib = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByDate);
var picsList = new List<BitmapImage>();

    foreach (StorageFile pic in picsLib)
    {
        var imgSrc = new BitmapImage();
        imgSrc.UriSource = new Uri(pic.Path, UriKind.Absolute);
        picsList.Add(imgSrc);
    }

PhotosView.ItemsSource = picsList;
```

But the images doesn't show up.

Right after, I tried using streams:

```
var imgSrc = new BitmapImage();
var picStream = await pic.OpenReadAsync();
imgSrc.SetSource(picStream);
picsList.Add(imgSrc);
```

Of course, I got `System.OutOfMemoryException`.

Next, I tried using thumbnails:

```
var imgSrc = new BitmapImage();
var picThumb = await pic.GetThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.PicturesView,
                200, Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailOptions.ResizeThumbnail);
imgSrc.SetSource(picThumb);
picsList.Add(imgSrc);
```

But I realized that it's just like the stream, `OutOfMemory` again. If I limit it to only get the thumbnails of 10 or 20 images, it works nice, but I really need to show all the photos.

XAML isn't the problem as it does the job fine when I limit the number of images to load.

The app is meant to be used by anyone who download it from the Windows Phone Store when finished, so the size of the images vary, as the pictures library of Windows Phone devices contains almost any photos stored on the user's phone, including photos from the device's camera, saved images, etc.

Comment: You didn't include any information about image sizes.  I'd consider that sort of essential.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Added that to the post.

Comment: Don't use "EDIT" in your posts; this isn't a forum.  I still don't see any information about how much storage your pictures are using; saying that "the size of the images vary" doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I can't just tell the size of the images, they vary depending on how much of them the user have stored on the device and their sizes. Streaming them isn't the right aproach as it throws `OutOfMemoryException` easily. It needs to be like setting the `UriSource` of a `BitmapImage` as an url. I can display hundreds of images this way without getting `OutOfMemoryExcpetion`.

Comment: Have you considered using a "paging" approach?  You don't need every thumbnail in memory at once; you only need those thumbnails in memory that the user is looking at, and maybe some on each side.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I will try the data virtualization aproach, paging doesn't fits good on a photo app I think. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no way to ever guarantee that you won't run out of memory with any of the above approaches.  And the reality is that unless you are resizing the images on the fly to a standard size, you will never really control how much memory you are using, even for just the visible images.

You MUST make the containing grid virtualized so that the byte array's are only allocated for the images that are actually visible to the user.

Yes, there will be some lag on most systems as you scroll as byte arrays are discarded and created, but that is the price you pay for being able to view them 'all'.

All of that being said, [here](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2006/06/17/5856.aspx) is a blog to help get you started.